# Rails before_update callback with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, nested, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two models (lets call then `A` and `B`).

`A` `has_many` `b`s and `B` `belongs_to` `A`.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bs, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :a
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates_associated :bs
end


class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a, inverse_of: :bs
  before_update :do_something, unless: Proc.new { |b| b.a.some_enum_value? if a }

  def do_something
    self.some_field = nil
  end

end
```

Other than that, `B` has a `before_update` callback that sets `some_field` to nil **if** `A` has `some_enum_value` set.

Since this relation is used on a **nested form**, that `before_update` from `B` is only being called if I update a attribute form `B`. If I only change a value form `A` that callback is not called.

How can I call `B`'s `before_update` when `A` is updated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For belongs to associations you can use the `touch` option:

```
class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a, inverse_of: :bs, touch: true
end
```

Which would update `a.updated_at` when you update B.
However this option does not exist for `has_many` relations since it could have potentially disastrous performance consequences (If an A has 1000s or more Bs).

You can roll your own however:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bs, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :a
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates_associated :bs
  after_update :cascade_update!

  def cascade_update!
    # http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each
    bs.find_each(batch_size: 100) do |b|
      b.update!(updated_at: Time.zone.now)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: From a scaling standpoint you need to be really careful when doing something like this. Write operations are expensive and usually you can solve this by proxying or using joins.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question... `touch` won't trigger `before_update` if I understand it correctly. So it won't trigger `do_something` which sets `some_field` to `nil`

Comment: @GProst you're absolutely right. I edited it to use `.update` which does trigger callbacks.