# Reject_if + errors added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Order` that could has many `texts`.

A text can have an activestorage attachment, and I validate this attachment with `active_storage_validations` gem.

I want to save valid texts and reject invalid texts, so I'm using `reject_if` option on the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`... but I want to keep errors then render the form if a text has been rejected.

This is my code:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :texts, dependent: :destroy, validate: false
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :texts, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :invalid_text?

  def invalid_text?(attributes)
    text = Text.new(attributes.tap { |att| att.delete(:_destroy) })
    return if text.valid?

    text.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      errors.add(:base, msg)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my controller:

```
def update
  if @order.update(order_params)
    @order.update!(creation_step: 'instructions')
    check_if_documents(@order, params[:file_upload_method])

    Text.counter_culture_fix_counts
    jump_to(:instructions)
  else
    flash.now.alert = @order.errors.full_messages.join('. ') if @order.errors.messages.any?
    render(:show)
  end
end
```

The problem is that `reject_if` is called after `@order.update` so there's never errors.

How can I validate the nested attributes before the parent update, while having access to activestorage attributes?

If i'm doing a `before_validation` callback, ActiveStorage attributes are not accessible with `nested_attributes_options` method...

Comment: Did you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376213/rails-before-update-callback-with-nested-attributes 
Have you tried using `before_update` or `before_validation` callbacks? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Also you can try calling `valid?` before updating your object, if the object is invalid the update action is never called so you can render your errors.

Comment: Hi @SgtPepper, thanks for your answer. I tried to validate the `order` but it's valid, because `validate` method doesn't perform a validation for the nested attributes. I could add `validates_associated :texts` but every texts will be rejected if only one is invalid. I would like to use a callback, but I don't what is the best way to get the nested attributes and remove the hash if the text built with these attributes is invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails before\_update callback with nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376213/rails-before-update-callback-with-nested-attributes)